# How to get the client-id and client-secret from keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

For a web application I need the client-id and client-secret from Keycloak. How can I access these in the web interface?

Answer (score 6):

in Keycloak 20 at least, the option is not "type: confidential." as far as I can tell, that setting no longer exists. instead, you have to turn on the "client authentication" switch and **then save the page**, or else the console will not show you the tabs you need. this should probably be updated in the documentation but as far as I can tell hasn't been done yet.

Answer (score 1):

its been awhile since this question asked but i will leave this answer here anyway
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69726692/2575875